# Maximum limit of started keywords exceeded

Tags: robotframework

I'm new to robot framework and I'm trying to do a simple test  data driven by using excel .this message is displayed
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test case has name `Open Browser`, and the first keyword in this test case is `Open Browser`. It creates an endless loop, so RF sees that and stops it at some point.

[image]

Similar topics on SO:

- [RobotFramework: Maximum limit of started keywords exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345168/robotframework-maximum-limit-of-started-keywords-exceeded)

and a thread on github:

- https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/1961