# Getting error in Robot framework when executed the Test Cases

Tags: pycharm, robotframework

I'm getting error as Maximum Limit of started keywords exceeded.

In Robot framework when executed the test case and validate the data against the Database byrunning a query. Can some one help me what is issue about?

[image]

Comment: pls share the test case code, so someone can take a look further. there are many posts around this error, and one of the recent is [maximum-limit-of-started-keywords-exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64749100/maximum-limit-of-started-keywords-exceeded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test calls the keyword Get Value, which calls the keyword Get Value. You've created an infinite recursion. Get Value calls Get Value which calls Get Value which calls Get Value which calls ...

The best solution is the simplest one: don't create a keyword that calls itself. If there is already a keyword with a given name, don't create another one with the same name. While you can make it work having two with the same name, it will make your test cases harder to understand.

If you have another keyword called Get Value and you simply must have two keywords with the same name, you can give the fully qualified name so robot doesn't call the same keyword again. For example, if your Get Value is trying to call the Get Value from robot.myTest, call it like this:

```
*** Keywords ***

Get Value

robot.myTest.Get Value
```